# Changing an innerText through Javascript after a CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a foldable menu, through CSS and JS. Css works (almost) correctly (the menu folds and unfolds, even if the class is not correctly applied) but not the JS code, which should change the innerText of the <li> acting as a button from ">" to "<" and opposite.

I have been messing around with js code for a while (making sure that document.getElementById is not undefined), but neither element.innerText or element.innerHTML seem to work properly.

I have two questions:

1. When applying an animation, and having two classes, shouldn't respect both classes (I mean, the navbar should be red)? Should I add nav class AFTER the animation is done, or fill the navbar in red color through the animation?
2. Why does ignore InnerText/InnerHTML instructions?? I have debugged the code and definitely goes through that instruction and I cannot understand why the change is not done...

```js
var navButton; 
var navbar;


const init = ()=>{
    navbar = document.getElementById("navbar"); 
    navButton = document.getElementById("foldButton");
    navButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(navbar.className==="init nav" || navbar.className==="fade-out-right nav"){
            navButton.InnerText=`<p>&lt</p>`;
            toggleFold();
        }
        else{
            navButton.InnerText=`<p>&gt</p>`;
            toggleFold();
        }
    });
}


const toggleFold = () => {
    if(navbar.className==="init nav" || navbar.className==="fade-out-right nav"){
        navbar.className="fade-in-left nav";
    }else{
        navbar.className="fade-out-right nav";
    }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Base styles */

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 4%;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.nav-list a{
  color:black
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.fade-in-left {
  animation-name: fade-in-left;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fade-in-left {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-4%);

  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(305px);
  }
}

.fade-out-right {
  animation-name: fade-out-right;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes fade-out-right {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(305px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-4%);
  }
}
```

```html
    <body onload="init()">
        <nav id="navbar" class="init nav">
          <ul class='nav-list'>
            <li><a href='#welcome-section'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='#projects'>Work</a></li>
            <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
            <li id="foldButton"><p>&gt</p></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: InnerText or InnerHTML should be lowercase like ``innerText`` or ``innerHTML`` have you tried that?

Comment: `navButton.innerHTML=\`<p>&lt</p>\`;` works just fine

Comment: Voting to close _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo -While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Oh, boy... There goes my IQ... Still, I have my question about CSS animation... Why the navbar goes full red if its class says so?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from my low IQ for the bad typo, whenever the color is not filled when using an animation, use internal container instead (in my case, I filled ul instead of navbar).